# Display one JSON into different IDs

Tags: javascript, html, json, getelementbyid

Here is a sample of my JSON:

```
{
  "Monday": [
    {
      "type": "menu_category",
      "recipe": "Soup"
    },
    {
      "type": "menu_item",
      "recipe": "Monday Soup 1"
    },
    {
      "type": "menu_item",
      "recipe": "Monday Soup 2"
    }
],
  "Tuesday": [
    {
      "type": "menu_category",
      "recipe": "Soup"
    },
    {
      "type": "menu_item",
      "recipe": "Tuesday Soup 1"
    },
    {
      "type": "menu_item",
      "recipe": "Tuesday Soup 2"
    }
],
... same format for "Wednesday", "Thursday", and "Friday"
}
```

Basically, I'd like to have the data for each day show up in a separate div/column.

So, I have the following HTML setup for that data:

```
             <div class="monday">
                <p class="weekday">Monday</p>
                <div id="outputMon"></div>
                <script src="scriptM.js"></script>
            </div>
            <div class="tuesday">
                <p class="weekday">Tuesday</p>
                <div id="outputTue"></div>
            <script src="script2.js"></script>
            </div>
            <div class="wednesday">
                <p class="weekday">Wednesday</p>
                <div id="outputWed"></div>
            <script src="scriptW.js"></script>
            </div>
            <div class="thursday">
                <p class="weekday">Thursday</p>
                <div id="outputThu"></div>
            <script src="scriptTh.js"></script>
            </div>
            <div class="friday">
                <p class="weekday">Friday</p>
                <div id="outputFri"></div>
            <script src="scriptF.js"></script>
            </div>
```

and I have different versions of the following js scripts to provide the data to the divs:

```
var outputTue = document.getElementById('outputWed');
var ajaxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "URL_TO_JSON";

ajaxhttp.open("GET", url, true);
ajaxhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/json");
ajaxhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxhttp.readyState == 4 && ajaxhttp.status == 200)
        {
            var jcontent= JSON.parse(ajaxhttp.responseText);
            console.log(jcontent);
            for(var i = 0 ; i < jcontent.Wednesday.length ; i++)
    {
        outputWed.innerHTML = outputWed.innerHTML + "<p class="+ jcontent.Wednesday[i].type + ">" + jcontent.Wednesday[i].recipe+"</p>";
    };
        }
}

ajaxhttp.send(null);
```

So, any single ONE script/div/ID will populate the data into the correct column.  I tried adding multiple  `getElementbyID` to the same script, and I could only get one to populate.

Then I tried 2 scripts, which basically were the same except for changing the "day" variables.  That kind of worked (the first div showed multiple copies of the same data, and the 2nd column was correct).  And adding 5 scripts simply didn't work.

How can I get the data into separate divs/columns/IDs?

Comment: `content-type` header is not necessary with `GET` request, since you don't send any content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the content, and convert the property name to the corresponding div ID.

```
for (var day in jcontent) {
    if (day.match(/day$/)) {
        var divid = 'output' + day.substr(0, 3);
        var output = document.getElementById(divid);
        var newContent = jcontent[day].map(({type, recipe}) => `<p class="${type}">${recipe}</p>`).join("");
        output.innerHTML = newContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, this provides me with the following error:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: substr is not defined`

I set up a codepen (removed the json call to simplify) to demonstrate the error: [link](https://codepen.io/justbriman/pen/RwPegvq)

Comment: Sorry, should be `day.substr`

Comment: This now provides this error:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null `

Comment: What is the value of `divid` when that happens? Are you missing that ID in the HTML?

Comment: I added a `console.log(divid);` line to that loop (line before `var output = ...` and the console shows only "output", so it's somehow not getting the day (or the first 3 letters, to append)

Comment: Not sure how that could happen unless you have an empty property name in `jcontent`.

Comment: Could this be because there is no key named "day" in the JSON?

Comment: OK, now I see where you've made changes to the original code.  That's working (thanks!), as far as getting the data into the correct divid's.  What I'm seeing now, is that after every entry, there is a blank comma on each line.  How do I remove that?

Comment: Need to give empty string argument to `join()` it defaults to comma.

Comment: Where's the empty string?  [link to codepen](https://codepen.io/justbriman/pen/RwPegvq)

Comment: That did it!  I sincerely appreciate all your help!